# Yii - Massive Assignment of a private field

Tags: php, yii

**TL;DR - How do I massively assign private fields in Yii?**

Any Yii experts on StackOverflow? The [YiiFramework forums](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/28480-setting-a-private-field-in-massive-assignment/page__p__137031__fromsearch__1#entry137031) didn't really help me out.

I've got a private field `hired` in my [CActiveRecord](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord) model that is dependent on another relation `jobCount`. Basically, if there is at least one valid `job` (stored in another table) associated with that member, they are consider hired.

Conventionally, I would set `hired` in the [afterFind](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#afterFind-detail) method, but that would mean loading the relation every time. For the sake of saving database queries, I would only like to load the relation if `hired` is needed. So I set `hired` to private, and can load the relation and set it once `getHired()` is called.

So far so good...

The problem arises once I incorporate the `hired` field in my CGridView. I'd like to be able to use the column filters, with a simple dropdown filtering on Yes or No. Upon filling out your filters, CGridView passes back a GET request, which you would set to a cleared model using massive assignment...

```
$model->attributes = $_GET['ModelName'];
```

Obviously I would like `hired` to get set as well, despite it being a private field. (I handle the searching for CGridView, don't worry about that.) I've made it a safe field in my model, but it doesn't get set.

- `setHired()` function doesn't get called
- `setAttribute()` function doesn't get called
- `setAttributes()` function doesn't get called

What's the correct way to do this? Clearly, I could just add an extra line in my controller action...

```
if (isset($_GET['ModelName']['hired'])) 
    $model->setHired($_GET['ModelName']['hired']);
```

...but I would really rather learn how to allow private fields to be massively assigned.

I realize that this is rather convoluted. If you see some way that I could streamline this `hired` bit, I'd appreciate that. Still, I would like to learn if there's a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you need just to add your attribute to the list of attributes.

```
public function attributeNames()
{
    $names = parent::attributeNames();
    $names[] = 'hired';
    return $names;
}
```